# ubuntu 14.04 - only performance and powersave governor available (i5 4.gen)

Tags: 14.04, cpu, cpufreq

After updating my ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 there only these to govenors available for my cpu, instead of additionally ondemand and conservative.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors 
performance powersave
```

My cpu is a *Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz*, my laptop a *LENOVO B5400 80B6QB0* and my kernel version is *3.14.1-031401-generic x86_64*

Before updating the four governors were available. If this is important, I have installed tlp and indicator-cpufreq.

How do I get back the missing two govenors? ondemand is really important to me because of power saving.

Comment: They are deprecated, so they are not really important. However, you can tweak the TLP configuration to enable basically all of the suggested improvements given by `powertop`. This will help to reduce consumption and also keep the temperature low.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/544266/why-are-missing-the-frequency-options-on-cpufreq-utils-indicator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not missing, but [depricated](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM3NDQ), since the Linux kernel (3.9 and later) includes the [Intel P-State Driver](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTI5Mzc).

Comment: OK, but is there any way to achieve the lower temperatures and better power consumption? From the links you've provided, it seems that available governors may not be the best regarding aforementioned aspects.

Comment: But from where should one now change the Governor then?

Comment: And should the cpufreq-utils be used at all then anymore? I used to use indicator-cpufreq to change the behaviour of my CPU Governor. No it is only possible to change between Powersave and Performance in it.

Answer (score 0):

Missing indeed, not deprecated at all. An useless/featureless like Intel P-State has no strength or arguments for deprecating anything (at least, yet)

For getting back the good old, amazing and unreplaceable ACPI driver working back again, we should enter on terminal:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

the line starting with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" should be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

ctrl+o for saving, ctrl+x for quitting, and then enter:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then:

```
sudo sync && sudo reboot
```

I did it right now, and got all those crucial options back again - and please, please, everyone, and asking it deeply from my heart, never name crucial options as "deprecated" again! ;)