# Why are missing the frequency options on cpufreq-utils indicator?

Tags: 14.10, cpufreq

I just upgraded to utopic and the indicator for cpufreq-utils just show two cpu frequency options: Power save and Performance.

Before in trusty:

[image: 14.04]

Now in utopic:

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you've got a newer Intel Processor it's because Ubuntu uses a new cpufreq driver called [P-State](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt). There are only two governors available for this driver, which are Performance and Powersave.

There are no frequencies listed because you can't actually clock the processor to a specific frequency with newer Core processors. Even if you set it to a specific frequency with the old ACPI cpufreq driver the CPU itself it what sets the frequency on this hardware based on voltage and temperature values.

If you really want to disable this and go back to ACPI cpufeq (older, slower) you need to [edit your GRUB config like in this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html), only adding `intel_pstate=disable` instead of `intel_pstate=enable`.

Run
`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`

and change the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save.

then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot the machine to see the change take effect.

Comment: I'll be using this new driver too. I just tought it was a bug because of the upgrade. Thanks

Comment: does disabling pstate has any drawbacks?

Comment: Nice "new driver".
I hate Windows for adding too many features, but in Linux it's the other extreme!

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu 14.10 by default uses intel_pstate for frequency control, which has only performance and powersave for governor options.  Should you wish to use the acpi frquency control, you will need to boot with the kernel parameter `intel_pstate=disable`.

To do this, you will need to edit your grub file

In a terminal (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
cd /etc/default
sudo cp grub grub.backup
sudo nano grub
```

Find the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

Append the words `intel_pstate=disable` to this line, before the final quote

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Despite all of this, I have started using intel_pstate to manage my computer, and find it to perform quite well.