# indicator-cpufreq not working with kernel 3.17?

Tags: kernel, cpufreq

indicator-cpufreq have just two option (powersave and performance) after upgrade to kernel 3.17. Is there any way to fix it?

I reinstall this program but still have same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running by default, the Intel Pstate system in Ubuntu 14.10.  To use the older ACPI method, you need to edit the grub file and reboot:

Open a terminal <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the folowing lines:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the Nano editor, look for the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`   At the end of the line add `intel_pstate=disable` The whole line shoud now look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

press the keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit Nano.  Then in the terminal, enter the following command to update Grub

`sudo update-grub`

You should now reboot your computer, and find that you are able to set the governors as you did in 14.04

This answer has been taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541143/indicator-cpufreq-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-14-10/541412#541412).

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to use newer ACPI method and fix this problem?

Comment: with indicator-cpufreq you can only change governor that performance or powersave.

Comment: According to [http://askubuntu.com/a/544272/142472], 1. there are only two governors available for the new driver, Performance and Powersave, and 2. using the older method is slower